# The difference between the use of equal or colon before variable

Tags: c, syntax

I was wondering: What is the difference between setting a variable with colon or equal.

As in:

```
struct file_operations ralink_gpio_fops =
{
    owner:      THIS_MODULE,
    ioct:      ralink_gpio_ioctl,
    open:       ralink_gpio_open,
    release:    ralink_gpio_release,
};
```

It seems like I can replace colons by equals. But it seems colons have more meanings when it:

```
int i=0;
printf("%d ",i);
i:i++;
printf("%d ",i);
//goto i;
```

In this case, if I remove double slash before `goto i`;. it will back to `i:i++;` and keep running. So does colon have more functions than equals? Or are they totally different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like some other things in C, some characters can mean different things in different situations.

In the first code snippet it's used to delimit  member field names from their initialization value. It's *not* used like the assignment. This syntax is also not standards compliant, but some extension of whatever compiler you use.

In the second snippet the colon is used to mark `i` as a *label*.

You also say that in the first example the colon is used instead of "equal", and there you mix the meaning of the *equality* `==` and the *assignment* `=` operators.

Answer (score 1):

In Usage 1, ":" is used for initialization. Here you can use "=" operator to replace ":". But again it is compiler specific.

In Usage 2, ":" used to mark "i" as label.

It can't be substituted by "=". i=i++ is different than i:i++.

Answer (score 0):

The two cases you talk about are completely different, and in neither case can `.` be substituted for `=` anyway.

In the line:

```
 i: i++;
```

it means there is a label `i`  (nothing to do with the variable `i`) . It does not affect the evaluation of the code after it. This is the same as :

```
blarrg: 
    i++;

// ...
goto blarrg;
```

---

In the declaration of the variable of `struct` type, this is a GCC extension. That code is illegal in Standard C. Standard C's *designated initializers* look like this:

```
.owner = THIS_MODULE;
.ioctl = ralink_gpio_ioctl;
```

Answer (score 0):

These are GCC extensions to C language. [See Designated Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: Designated initializers are specified by C99 (which the page you links also points out). So I wouldn't call them "extensions" any longer.

Comment: @cnicutar gcc supports an alternative syntax for designated initializers , which OP posted. Don't ask me why, but I guess they rolled their own well before the C standard committee had the idea of doing so.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh, I wasn't paying attention. I stand corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a symbol can be used in different meanings based on the context. suppose, - is treated as subtraction operator in expression like a - b and the same symbol - is treated as negative sign in expression like -a + b 
 Similarly color (:) has different meaning in different contexts.
When : is used in first case (at structure elements in the structure definition), it is setting **bitfields**. 
Generally when a structure is created like
struct unit
{
    int e1;
    int e2:4;
    int e3:6;
    int e4:6;
};
on a 16-bit compiler, 16 bits (2 bytes) are allocated for e1,
4 bits are allocated for e2,
6 bits are allocated for e3 and 
6 bits are allocated for e4.
Together, size of the structure become 4 bytes.
If bitfields are not specified, the size of the structure would become 8 bytes.
To utilize memory efficiently, some compiler have this(BIT-FIELDS) provision.

This mechanism is useful when you want to store a month number(which can be between 1 and 12). If a normal integer is used, 16 bits would be used where 12 bits are always unused. if month:4 is used, we can save those 12 bits.

The second one is a **goto label**, and we better not to use them.